# Magento 1.7 and Owl Carousel 2

Tags: magento-1.7, jquery

I'm currently trying to get Owl Carousel working with Magento 1.7 and getting this error in console. googling i can't seem to find anything about it.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._core.$element.on is not a function
at new Lazy (owl.slider.js:1874)
at Owl.<anonymous> (owl.slider.js:183)
at Function.c (jquery-1.4.2.min.js:16)
at Function.each (jquery-1.4.2.min.js:16)
at new Owl (owl.slider.js:181)
at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> (owl.slider.js:1797)
at Function.each (jquery-1.4.2.min.js:16)
at init.each (jquery-1.4.2.min.js:16)
at init.$.fn.owlSlider (owl.slider.js:1795)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):315)
```

Answer (score 0):

there should be some issue with your jQuery and Owl-Carousel , you can check below points

1) Your jQuery lib should be loaded before Owl-Carousel

2) `jQuery.noconflict()` line should be there before Owl-Carousel

3) Owl-Carousel lib should not be loaded twice in a single page.

above are the things you need to take care before you initialize the Owl-Carousel

Comment: So the normal jQuery lib is loaded first, there is also a jquery-ui.1.8.9.custom.min.js that is loaded after the Owl-Carousel. could that be a conflict?

no-conflict.js is loaded before owl-slider but not jquery

Comment: @DylanCrow I dont think jqueryui has problem but please `jQuery.noconflict()` add this line before owl and after jQuery

Comment: Added jQuery.noConflict() to the start of owl and at the end of jQuery file. still getting the same error. hmmmm